# BUILDING ANDROID FOR AM1808 EVM

Tags: android, git, arm, embedded-linux, porting

I am trying to port android froyo on my EVM AM1808 Kit.

I am using ubuntu 14.04 version. I have followed the steps which has been described in the following link,

[Android Froyo For AM1808 EVM Kit](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/TI-AM1808-Android-FroYo-DevKit_UserGuide)

I have created all the export paths as described in the link.

after,

`curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo`

command I got the following output:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1363  100  1363    0     0   1778      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1777
```

Is it right ?

After that I execute command for **Repo Init**,

```
/root/bin/repo init -u git://gitorious.org/rowboat/manifest.git -m rowboat-froyo-am1808.xml
```

when I execute the above command I got the error like,

`/root/bin/repo: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token newline'
/root/bin/repo: line 1: <!DOCTYPE html>`

I'm not able to build the android source for AM1808 EVM.

I'm stuck here.

How should I build the Android source for AM1808 EVM kit.

Comment: Shell scripts don't usually have a doctype... if you try that link in a browser, you'll see that what you've downloaded is a 404 error page.

Comment: This is the only link through which i can init my repo. Is there any solution for that. ?

Comment: Note that that wiki page is nearly 4 years old - things move around on the internet. I could type "git-repo" into my search box, but then again so could you ;)

Comment: so what is should use to build it ?

Comment: can you provide me a guide or something so that i can follow it.

Comment: Here's a complete step-by-step guide to _downloading something from a slightly different URL_: 1) Locate [the new URL](https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo) 2) download it.

Comment: I suspect you're seeing an html-formatted error from either the server, *or from an ISP deciding to jump in the way of it*.

Answer (score 0):

if you havent solved the issue yet- please do consider taking off the `-u` option in

```
repo init -u git://gitorious.org/rowboat/manifest.git -m rowboat-froyo-am1808.xml
```

I was able to fix similar issue with this.